# How to position something inside of a container HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently trying to make a website. I want to have text boxes explaining what I am trying to do and a tiny about us underneath. I want to incorporate a grey border around the text and keep the text part white. I was originally trying to use margin to accomplish this but just switched to container because it worked better. When I try to place the text boxes in container using absolute it doesn't allow me to. To make the text boxes the most effective I need to place exact coordinates rather then just float right or left. Below is the code I am trying to incorporate. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
div2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  background-color: #3374FF;
  width: 320px;
  style="position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #3374FF;
  padding: 5px
  margin: 5px
}


.site_container {
              max-width: 650px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              background-color: blue;
 }

<div class="site_container">

<div2 style="position: absolute; top:570px; left:245px">
<fontcolor="white">Services/Projects we offer:
<br />
<br />-Websites
<br />-Mobile Development
<br />-Design
<br />
</div2>
</font>
```

This is an example of one html text box. There are three others and are positioned similarly. Thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated

Comment: div2? What is div2

Comment: You have lot of mistakes in your code. there is nothing like `<div2>` and `fontcolor`. you can use multiple `div` you need not increment/add a integer to it.

Comment: I will edit the code. It is the constraints of the text box

Comment: and dont use the `font` tag as it is not supported in HTML5. Please read this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: It is still wrong. There is no property like this ` style="position: absolute;` it should just be `position:absolute`;

Comment: @this.Believer.   I changed the code. Thank you. But how will I set exact coordinates

Comment: I did what you said and the text box went to the top rather then where I wanted to place it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid using `<font>` (too old now) or `<fontstyle>` / `<div2>` elements that don't exist. Then, you should use `<ul>` list rather than `<br>` list, semantic is better like that. And if you want to place your child element by using absolute coordinate relative to its parent, you have to set a `position : relative` (or absolute) on the parent "site_container" as well.

(I don't know y/x coord you want)

```
.site_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.site_child{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  background-color: #3374FF;
  width: 320px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #3374FF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
<div class="site_container">
    <div class="site_child">
        <span>Services/Projects we offer:</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Websites</li>
            <li>Mobile Development</li>
            <li>Design</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**
If you want to place elements side to side. Why not using **flexbox** on parent element with `display: flex;` What do you think about that ?
 https://jsfiddle.net/nesquimo/osgkfqtq/3/

```
.site_container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.site_child{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  background: #3374FF;
  margin: 5px;
}

<div class="site_container">
    <div class="site_child">
        <span>Services/Projects we offer:</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Websites</li>
          <li>Mobile Development</li>
          <li>Design</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="site_child">
        <span>Services/Projects we offer 2:</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Websites</li>
          <li>Mobile Development</li>
          <li>Design</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="site_child">
        <span>Services/Projects we offer 3:</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Websites</li>
          <li>Mobile Development</li>
          <li>Design</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you use list to place objects beside each other. I have researched into and couldn't find a way to find how to place them side to side

Comment: What do you mean by "objects" ? <li>Websites</li>
            <li>Mobile Development</li>
            <li>Design</li> ? Or other <div class="site_child"> ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will they still remain text boxes if using this method

Comment: What do you mean by remain text boxes ? Flexbox method allow you to put elements side to side and let you change order or position (row or column). It's a very powerful tool for aligning items : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks a lot for the all the help. It is great!